# Solving Inequalities using Mathematica

Tags: equation-solving, linear-algebra, inequalities

How can I solve this inequality using Mathematica?

```
Sqrt[B^2 + J^2] Cosh[(2 J)/T ] < J Sinh[  (2 Sqrt[B^2 + J^2])/T]
```

where T, J, and B are reals and they are >0.

Comment: I doubt that something that complicated can be solved analytically at all. `Reduce[ {  Sqrt[B^2 + J^2] Cosh[(2 J)/T] < J Sinh[(2 Sqrt[B^2 + J^2])/T], {B, J, T} > 0}, {B, J, T} ] ` quickly returns saying that "This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Reduce".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can divide both sides by `T`. This reduces the number of variables to 2:
$$ j=\frac{J}{T},\quad b=\frac{B}{T}.$$

To visualize inequality, one can use `ContourPlot`. The inequality is fulfilled in the green area.

```
ContourPlot[Sqrt[b^2 + j^2] Cosh[2 j] - j Sinh[2 Sqrt[b^2 + j^2]],{j,0,1},{b,0,1},
PlotRange->{-3,1},
Contours->20,
ColorFunctionScaling->False,
ColorFunction -> (If[# > 0., RGBColor[0,0.5+#/2, 0], GrayLevel[(1 - #)/3]] &)]
```

[image]